# Google Login API requires two clicks initially

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-api, google-oauth

We've moved our Google login code inside our angularJS controller and after the page initially loads, two clicks are required for a login. Tried moving the init code after the page loads but it still requires two clicks initially. Any idea what might be causing this? Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="googleLogin" ng-click="onGoogleLogin()"
        class="btn btn-sm btndefault">
  Login
</button>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
function GoogleLogin($scope) {

  $scope.onGoogleLogin = function() {

    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        //Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            //cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
        });

        var element = document.getElementById('googleLogin');

        auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(response) {

            //https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference
            var profile = response.getBasicProfile();

            console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
            console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
            console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.

            console.log('ID Token: ' + response.getAuthResponse().id_token);
        }, 
        function(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
    });
  }

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try adding a `console.log` after `$scope.onGoogleLogin = function() {` to see if it's called the first time you click.

Comment: Matt, yes it's hitting that the first time I click

Comment: And you get no errors in console either?

Comment: No errors at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better implemented as a directive:

```
app.directive("googleLoginDirective", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
        gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            //Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                //cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
            });

            ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶d̶o̶c̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶.̶g̶e̶t̶E̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶B̶y̶I̶d̶(̶'̶g̶o̶o̶g̶l̶e̶L̶o̶g̶i̶n̶'̶)̶;̶
            var element = elem[0];

            auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
            function(response) {

                //https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference
                var profile = response.getBasicProfile();

                console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
                console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
                console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
                console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.

                console.log('ID Token: ' + response.getAuthResponse().id_token);
            }, 
            function(error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            });
        });
    }
})
```

### Usage

```
<button type="button" google-login-directive
        class="btn btn-sm btndefault">
  Login
</button>
```

When the AngularJS framework instantiates the directive, it invokes the `gapi.load` function and attaches the Google click handler to the element.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 0):

You've setup your function to run when the button is clicked, however you call `attachClickHandler` inside that function. Therefore the click handler only gets attached after the first click and that's why the OAuth flow launches on the second.

You need to change your code so that it just runs on page load. There's no need to put it in an `ng-click` attribute because `attachClickHandler` handles all that for you.